# Azure DevOps Deploying a .NET Desktop App to a local machine

Tags: publish, desktop-application

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to get the `.ZIP` archive which is produced in a build pipeline for a Desktop App.

I would like to get the .ZIP archive deployed to one or more VMs in my test lab (not in the azure cloud).

I have seen tutorials on how to do this for Websites, but none for deploying a .NET Winforms Applications which is produced as a `.zip` artifact in my pipeline.

Any help in pointing me to some guidance on how to make this happen would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe have a release pipeline upload the artifact/ZIP to azure storage (Azure CLI, az storage blob upload) and then download from storage onto the VMs using the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install an agent to a machine on your network and put it into an agent pool.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53386.azure-devops-create-configure-agent.aspx

Once you've done this, you'll be able to deploy to machines on your network the same way that an Azure Build Agent can deploy to a machine in Azure.